# Is it possible to reload continuously Rewarded Video Ads in Admob for Android?

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am considering implementing rewarded video ads as a continuous full screen advertising until the user manually interrupts the otherwise endless ad sequence. I tried to implement **Admob Rewarded Video Ads**, one playing after the other, but it doesn't work as one could normally suppose, and worse, because it doesn't seem to be Google's expected behavior, so there doesn't seem to be any tool to implement this desired feature.

Let's see the code provided by **Google's Admob**:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-4824494878097656/8403117409");

    // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(objGloContext);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                mRewardedVideoAd.show(); //this shows ad immediately
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
            mRewardedVideoAd.destroy(objGloContext);
            mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(objGloContext);
            mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new     AdRequest.Builder().build()); //use this id for testing
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    });
```

As long as I know, Google doesn't really provide any instruction to programmatically close the ad, and destroy doesn't close it either, so
I cannot restart it recursively in `onRewardedVideoCompleted()`.
Then, do you have any other idea? Thanks

Comment: Any idea about that?

Comment: Hi mahmoudismail. I simply ended up not implementing AdMob in my App, mainly because AdMob Ads are CPC (per click), and I want only CPM (per thousand views). Besides, I think that AdMob Rewarded Video is coded to only be closed by explicit touch by the user of closing button. Finally, I found what I needed in Smaato Video Ads: it has automatic closing after the impression has been registered, so I can now reload consecutive Video Ads until the user dimisses the Video Ads by touching the screen. Also, Smaato is strong in CPM.

Comment: Okay thanks for your replay :). Good Day!